# Finding conditional probability of die rolls in R

Tags: r, probability, dice, stat

I am very unfamiliar with R, yet was assigned to do simple statistics problems for a probability course in the language.

I have to find the conditional probability that if the sum of two die rolls of 6 sided die is 7, then the first die is a 2. The answer should be 1/6, as there are 6 ways to sum to 7 (1-6, 2-5,3-4,4-3,5-2,6,1), but I can't figure out how to insert probabilities that are not based on a distribution.

I've downloaded `dice` package, and tried to use `getSumProb` and `getEventProb`, but it's been to no avail.

Comment: Can you show some of the code you tried to implement? That will help shed some light on how we can best help you.

Comment: getSumProbs(ndicePerRoll= 2, nsidesPerDie= 6, nkept = 2, dropLowest= FALSE, sumModifier=0, perDieModfifier=0,  perDieMinOfOne = TRUE) is what I started with but honestly I don't know where to insert that the desired value is 7. I wanted to then use getEventProb(nrolls= 2, ndicePerRoll= 1, nsidesPerDie= 6, eventList, orderMatters = TRUE) and use this to make sure die 1 =2. This course has no coding base, it is solely to prepare me for an actuarial exam, and we were never taught any R or given a textbook. I apologize for having made very little progress!

Answer (score 0):

You are mostly there. I think the confusion might just be the output of the function. Run the following lines:

```
probs <- getSumProbs(2,6,2)[["probabilities"]]
View(probs)
```

You set the correct values you just need to view your results. When you run the second line you will see a matrix. Column 1 ("Sum") is the sum of the two dice, column 2 ("Probability") is the probability of that sum, and column 3 ("Ways to Roll") is how many possible dice combinations sum to that specific number.

You will see that if you look at the row that is sum 7 the probability is ~.167 which is 1/6.